# How do you find the number of occurrence within a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to find how many times per case_id does `email_response` occurs in the example below:

```
json_obj = [{
    'case_id': 1000,
    'type': 'email',
    'customer_id': 42571,
    'date': '2015-01-20',
},
    {
    'case_id': 1000,
    'type': 'email_response',
    'customer_id': 42571,
    'date': '2015-01-21',
},
    {
    'case_id': 1021,
    'type': 'email',
    'customer_id': 88686,
    'date': '2015-01-24',
}]
```

So in this case, the answer would be `1` for `case_id = 1000` and `0` for `case_id = 1021`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another dictionary and keep on updating the count like this

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for obj in json_obj:
...     if obj['type'] == 'email_response':
...         result[obj['case_id']] = result.get(obj['case_id'], 0) + 1
...         
>>> result
{1000: 1, 1021: 0}
```

Since we pass `0` as the second parameter, the `dict.get` method will return `0` if it cannot find the key being retrieved, otherwise the actual value corresponding to the key. You can do the same like this

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for obj in json_obj:
...     result[obj['case_id']] = result.get(obj['case_id'], 0) + (obj['type'] == 'email_response')
...     
>>> result
{1000: 1, 1021: 0}
```

Since Python's booleans are subclasses of `int`, `True` will be `1` and `False` will be `0`. So, the result of `(obj['type'] == 'email_response')` will be added with the current value of `case_id` in the `result` dictionary.

Comment: Great, I am trying to familiarize myself with list and dictionary in Python and didn't know such thing existed. Thanks!